# debezium topic routing 3 tables

Tags: regex, debezium

I have 3 table types

```
raw_app_logs_$daystamp
raw_users_logs_$daystamp
city_logs_$daystamp
```

Now the following topic Reroute works perfectly for 1 table type:

```
transforms=Reroute
transforms.Reroute.type=io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter
transforms.Reroute.topic.regex=(.*)raw_app_logs(.*)
transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement=$1raw_app_logs
```

This takes `raw_app_logs_20200720`, `raw_app_logs_20200721` etc and writes it into the `raw_app_logs` topic perfectly well.

How do I add the other 2 entries so that they are matched and sent to their topic names?

EG: `raw_app_logs_20200720` goes to the topic `raw_app_logs` while `raw_users_logs_20200720` goes to a topic named `raw_users_logs` and `city_logs_20200720` goes to a topic named `city_logs` in the same config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

Use regex groups and then just print the first group:

```
transforms=Reroute
transforms.Reroute.type=io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter
transforms.Reroute.topic.regex=(.*)([^0-9]).*
transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement=$1
```

Comment: Hi @rezizter,

I am getting the following error when trying to push data from 2 different tables. The first table changes are flowing fine.

Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject

error code: 409

Comment: Hi @Vikash. Are your schemas different? in our case our schemas are the same (we write daily tables and i needed to stream each daily table which has the same schema)

Comment: Hi @rezizter,
Thanks for your reply, Yes our schemas are different. Basically, we want the changes from two different tables into the same topic. Both the tables are having different sets of data but logically both are related. Like employee entity and address entity and account details entity etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a different transforms alias for each table :

```
transforms=app, users, city
transforms.app.type=io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter
transforms.app.topic.regex=(.*)raw_app_logs(.*)
transforms.app.topic.replacement=$1raw_app_logs

transforms.users.type=io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter
transforms.users.topic.regex=(.*)raw_users_logs(.*)
transforms.users.topic.replacement=$1raw_users_logs

transforms.city.type=io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter
transforms.city.topic.regex=(.*)city_logs(.*)
transforms.city.topic.replacement=$1city_logs
```